Fast growing tree species in Borneo with good coppice capability
I am looking for tree species that have good coppicing ability in the lowland tropical climate of northern Borneo, specifically in Brunei, and the Malaysian states of Sarawak and Sabah.

The tree should be fast growing and have the ability to regrow after being periodically coppiced.
Trees that tolerate coppicing when young or inherently smaller tree species are preferred due to space constraints and ease of coppicing.
The tree species should be a native species or widely naturalized so that I can easily source seeds or seedings.

Anecdotes suggest that Cassia fistula (naturalized), Lagerstroemia speciosa, and Syzygium myrtifolium (native) have some coppicing ability, but I could not find information about how well they regenerate after coppicing.
